# express jwt error handling in nest js graphql

Tags: express, graphql, nestjs, apollo, express-jwt

I use express JWT with nest js and use it in gateway graphql.
I want to return error when my token has error including expiration error or invalid error after calling any graphql api.

Here is the code that I use express JWT in main file of my gateway:

```
app.use(
    graphqlUploadExpress(),
    expressJwt({
      secret: secretCallback,
      algorithms: ['HS256'],
      credentialsRequired: false,
    }),
  );
```

and the following code is my validation when token is invalid:

```
function (err, req, res, next) {
    const { ip, method, originalUrl, headers } = req;
    const requestMeta = { headers, ip, method, originalUrl, error: err };
    if (err.message === 'jwt expired') {
      Logger.error('Gateway JWT Expired', requestMeta);
      res.send(401, { code: 'gateway-token-expired', message: 'Token is expired' });
    } else if (err.code === 'invalid_token') {
      Logger.error('Gateway JWT Invalid', requestMeta);
      res.send(401, { code: 'gateway-token-invalid', message: 'Token is invalid' });
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  };
```

I want that `res.status(err.status).send({ message: err.message });` return the error message back to user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help...

```js
function (err, req, res, next) {
    const { ip, method, originalUrl, headers} = req;
    const requestMeta = { headers, ip, method, originalUrl, error: err};
    if (err.message === 'jwt expired') {
        Logger.error('Gateway JWT Expired', requestMeta);
        res.status(err.status || 401).send({ message: 'Token is expired or gateway-token-expired'});
    } else if (err.code === 'invalid_token') {
        Logger.error('Gateway JWT Invalid', requestMeta);
        res.status(err.status || 401).send({ message: 'Token is invalid or gateway-token-invalid'});
    } else {
        res.status(err.status || 501).send({ message: `${err.message} or ${err.code}`});
    }
}
```

Comment: not worked ! do you know how can I throw exception to graphql gateway with nest js ?

Comment: Don't throw an exception from the GraphQL context function!

Comment: the problem was with header of response.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that when I send response to client I did not set headers to response to due to this client was getting CROS policy.

```
 res
    .status(401)
    .set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
    .send({ code: 'gateway-token-expired', message: 'Token is expired' });
```